# The type of the expresssion must be an array type but it resolved to string

Tags: java, arrays, string, types

Its part of code in java. Unfortunately I got an error when argz is appearing:he type of the expresssion must be an array type  but it resolved to String.

Any ideas why i cant do `argz[i]!='\0'` and so on? I would be grateful for any help.

```
public  static int parsuj(String argz) throws Zakres,NieprawidlowaDana {
    int i=0;
    while(argz[i] != '\0'){         
        if(argz[i]=='-')
            throw new Zakres();
        if( !argz.isdigit(i) )
            throw new NieprawidlowaDana();

        i=i+1;
    }
    int x = Integer.parseInt(argz);

    return x;

}
```

Comment: where do you input argz also why are you even trying to compare it to `\0`?

Comment: i put argz. I compare a element of string which should be char.

Comment: i write in in c++ and now trying to transform it co java. I thought it is a normal thing to check string.

Comment: first of all to iterate over characters of string, use String#getCharAt(int index) and you have mixed string and array concept here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per immibis comment, Java is indeed not C. So string operations really differ. See the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for which methods you can use on a string.

For your code snippet:

```
public static int parsuj(String argz) throws Zakres,NieprawidlowaDana {
    for (int i = 0; i < argz.length(); i++) {
        if (argz.charAt(i) == '-')
            throw new Zakres();
        if (!Character.isDigit(argz.charAt(i)))
            throw new NieprawidlowaDana();
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(argz);
}
```

Explanation: Use the method `String.charAt(int)` for retrieving single characters from a string. For checking if a character is a digit, you must use the static method `isDigit` from class `Character`. And - last but not least - a string knows its length and - other than in C - strings are not null-terminated.

Comment: I can't seem to find where `x` is used, nor where `argz` is declared.

Comment: confusion over `x` and `argz` I thinks

Comment: Exactly. I simply copied the OP's code snippet that just got edited. Will edit my answer.

Comment: cool now it make sense. It seems i should read more before posting this problem. Anyway thanks for helping me with that!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the String method `charAt`:

```
public  static int parsuj(String argz) throws Zakres,NieprawidlowaDana {

    for(int i = 0; i < argz.length(); i++){         
        if(argz.charAt(i) =='-')
            throw new Zakres();
        if( !(argz.charAt(i) >= '0' && argz.charAt(i) <= '9' ) )
            throw new NieprawidlowaDana();
        }
    return Integer.parseInt(argz); //I'll assume here you wanted to parse argz
}
```

Comment: what on earth is `int x = Integer.parseInt(x);

    return x;` though

Comment: @Java1 That's a bug too, I think he maybe wanted to parse argz

Comment: @user3402584 Edited the answer to solve that too, you can do my way or as Seelenvirtuose suggests

Comment: using str.length() is a more normal way to do it I thinks

Comment: You should know that java has no 0-termination of Strings

Comment: Besides declaring variable "int x = ..." and directly "return x" could - or better should - be concatenated to simply "return ...", your code still does not compile: you declare "int i = 0", and then declare "int i" again in the for loop. And that's not the only problem. You still increment i as a last step in the for loop, which leads to a wrong behavior.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thank you for your comments from now I'll make code fragments completely right as for to "copy and paste". I used to answer just to the question and not to review the full code but I'll change my answers style.